# How to narrow down what is taking 100% CPU on alternating cores

Tags: google-chrome, cpu

Whilst watching video one core will spike to 100% for a few moments drop off and then another core will spike to 100%.

## 30 second `htop` .gif

[image: one cpu 100%.gif]

## 30 second `conky` .gif

[image: one cpu conky 100%.gif]

Other points:

- CPU MHz running over 3000 Mhz (3 GHz) when it is normally around 1000 MHz
- Temperature about 20 degrees Celsius above normal.

## Narrowing it down

While writing this question I accidentally closed the chrome tab with the video on external monitor. CPU frequencies and load dropped to normal. I've noticed before how `apt-get` will spike a single CPU to 100% but this problem is nothing like that.

The process causing abnormal behaviour is `chrome` but what steps can be taken to narrow it down? ie Can a certain sub-process be identified within video codec-land (whatever you call it) and targeted for bug reporting?

### Chrome Version

Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: which version of chrome are you using? Another user had chrom65 spiking his cpu. I forget the name of the process that was doing it, but reverting to chrome 56 solved the issue as 56 doesn't have that process. PS - the process also used a lot of RAM. and he would crash with 4 tabs open

Comment: @ravery Thanks for comment. Chrome version 63 added to question. Note that I restarted the video after accidentally closing it. The problem did not reoccur. Also note I think I've been using this version for a couple of weeks and never noticed it before. Note I installed kernel 4.14.12 for Meltdown CPU security hole today. Final note I didn't reboot between problem and restarting video.

Comment: I was also curios how to do that in htop and discovered the "F" key with which i can follow a process. Starting from sort by CPU "P" i selected the process with follow "F" and then pressed "F5" for tree again.

Comment: @noreabu That sounds very interesting. Would you care to post an answer in suitable format? I'd be happy to up-vote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `htop` you can

1. sort by CPU usage with **P**
2. follow the process with **F**
3. Switch to Tree view with **t** / **F5**

Comment: Accepting this answer but, the problem is no longer present four years later...