# System Freeze After Build Operations

Tags: compiling, 17.10, freeze, logging

I'm using Ubunut 17.10 on a Dell XPS 13 laptop.

I'm experiencing system freezes after I build software. Typically my computer will freeze for anywhere between 2 - 30 seconds. My mouse and keyboard stop responding (although input is buffered and then delivered once the system starts responding again), the application switcher doesn't work (although again, it accepts the buffered input once the system unfreezes), application windows don't update, and the cpu fan kicks in at full-speed. This happens when I am using Eclipse, Qt Creator, or Cmake from the command line, and happens whether I am programming in C, C++, or Python.

Given that the cpu fan kicks in and the system unfreezes by itself, I am guessing that it is some sort daemon/program running at 100% and locking everything else up. Also, given that it happens after build operations I am beginnig to wonder whether it's a file indexing operation, but that's only a guess.

I have tried to use the system monitor and the command line program 'top' to troubleshoot, but I haven't found anything definitive yet. I also haven't found any insights in /var/log/kern.log or /var/log/syslog.

Are there any other logs that I should be checking, like a gnome settings log or something like that? Is there a daemon log that I can check? (I couldn't find one in /var/log, or anything on my system named daemon.log). Are there any other tips I should follow to work out what is happening on my system during the freeze?

Thanks!

Comment: I would use `htop` or `conky` as illustrated [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992779/how-to-narrow-down-what-is-taking-100-cpu-on-alternating-cores) to start gaining some insight. Also note sometimes `sudo apt-get` shows similar traits to your build function.

Comment: See if [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841379/qtcreator-freezes-after-few-minutes-of-use/1505714#1505714) helps for the Qt Creator users.